# Logging configuration for Flask applications run by paster.deploy

Tags: python, flask, paster

The access log and root log for my Flask app was helped by zcbuildout. That's fine. Now I wondered how do I get logging from my own app. I know how to use logging library but paster just do not log it in the console or anywhere.

Thanks

Here's my config:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, wsgi, myapp

[handlers]
keys = console, accesslog

[formatters]
keys = generic, accesslog

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s] %(message)s

[formatter_accesslog]
format = %(message)s

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[handler_accesslog]
class = FileHandler
args = (os.path.join(r'.', 'access.log'), 'a')
level = INFO
formatter = accesslog

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_wsgi]
level = INFO
handlers = accesslog
qualname = wsgi
propagate = 0

[logger_myapp]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console
qualname = myapp

[filter:translogger]
use = egg:Paste#translogger
setup_console_handler = False
logger_name = wsgi

[app:main]
use = egg:myapp#debug
filter-with = translogger
...
```

Here's how I tried to log:

```
import logging as log

def myfunc():
    log.debug("show me the log")
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, this logging problem was resolved. Referring to the manual, Flask has configured its own logger. So to do logging, please use flask.logger

Documentation is here:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.logger